# Using the value of a field in an S57 file with Mapserver 7

Tags: ogr, mapserver

I'm relatively new to Mapserver and I'm having an issue with the line style for depth contours in my map.  Basically I just want the depth to be written along the line.

I can get text to appear along the line, but I can't for the life of me get the value of the VALDCO field of the DEPCNT to show up.  I think my basic problem is that I am not understanding how to access this information in my map file.  Here's what I'm working with:

```
LAYER
    NAME "DEPCNT_CA276241"
    TYPE LINE
    DUMP true
    TEMPLATE fooOnlyForWMSGetFeatureInfo
    EXTENT -66.1660611 44.6667528 -63.6660696 46.0000945
    DATA "DEPCNT"
    METADATA
      'ows_title' 'DEPCNT_CA276241'
      "gml_include_items" "VALDCO"
      "gml_VALDCO_type" "Real"
      "gml_VALDCO_precision" "2"
    END #metadata"
    STATUS ON
    CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
    CONNECTION "./s57/CA276241.000"
    TRANSPARENCY 100
    PROJECTION
      'proj=longlat'
      'datum=WGS84'
      'no_defs'
    END #projection

    LABELITEM 'VALDCO'
    CLASS
      NAME 'DEPCNT'
      STYLE
        WIDTH 0.91
        COLOR 0 170 255
      END #style
      LABEL
        #TEXT "[VALDCO]"
        SIZE 10
        COLOR 255 0 0
        ANGLE FOLLOW
        POSITION AUTO
        FORCE TRUE
        ANTIALIAS TRUE
      END #label
    END #class
END #layer DEPCNT_CA276241
```

My understanding from reading the documentation I can find is that the depth value (which is the VALDCO field of the feature) should be used as the label. Unfortunately the number is not showing up.

I also tried commenting out the LABELITEM and replacing it with the TEXT "[VALDCO]" line you can see in the code.  Some of the documentation suggested that was how to use a field.... all that does is write the literal text on the contour line.

So, I am missing something here.... suggestions?

Comment: How does ogrinfo report the names of the attributes? Run it with -so switch for getting just a summary.

Comment: Here's the output, down the the first feature anyway...

Comment: Odd, everything looks correct. You have probably already tried `LABELITEM "VALDCO"` and `LABELITEM VALDCO`. Your LABEL is missing TYPE but I guess that it is not mandatory. And I trust that you have data in VALDCO,

Comment: Could it be possible to get a sample of S57 data to play with?

Comment: I believe I did try both of those options for LABELITEM.... but I will try them again tomorrow.  Can't give you that particular S57 file, but I will try this with another one that I know I can pass along.  It's probably worth trying the other one anyway in case there is a problem with the file.

Comment: I just confirmed those alternative don't work, and I tried using a different S57 file, and had the same problems.  US S57 charts are available for free from NOAA here:  http://www.charts.noaa.gov/ENCs/ENCs.shtml

Comment: I used the US1G09M chart to test against...

Comment: Do you mean http://www.charts.noaa.gov/ENCs/US1GC09M.zip?

Comment: That particular chart file is in the zip file you linked to;  /ENC_ROOT/UG1G09M/US1GC09M.000

Comment: Just in case you're not familiar with S57 files, the 000 extension is the base chart, and the increasing numbers are updates.  You don't need all the updates.

Comment: Still unable to get this to work.  As a work around I made classes for the style at 10 metre intervals of VALDCO - it works if used in an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem with this is that the VALDCO is stored as a number, not a string when Mapserver reads it in.  The TEXT for the class **MUST BE** string data.  The class definition below works, where the toString() function has converted the numeric data to string.

```
CLASS
  NAME 'DEPCNT'
  TEXT (toString([VALDCO], "%.0f"))
  STYLE
    WIDTH 0.91
    COLOR 0 170 255
  END #style
  LABEL
    SIZE 10
    ANGLE FOLLOW
    POSITION AUTO
    FORCE TRUE
    ANTIALIAS TRUE
  END #label
END #class
```

If I get the time I'll go in and update the Mapserver documentation on GitHub to make sure this is clear.